# How to stream a video using google's vrVideoView

Tags: android, android-studio, video-streaming, google-vr-sdk, vrvideoview

I am trying to stream a video using Google's `vrVideoView` on an Android app. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlcBadfFUC0&t=7s) is the video I am currently trying to load as a test.  Though, eventually I would like to load a video from a Google Drive URL. I am currently using the code from [this](http://trimensions.org/node/83) tutorial. I don't know if there is something wrong with the video link or if I need to do something with the URI or URL before passing it to `vrVideoView.loadVideo()`.

Steps I have taken:
Added following lines to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I have edited the code in the MainActivity in the videoloader class doInBackground function of my MainActivity.java file from the above tutorial  to be:

```
options.inputType = VrVideoView.Options.TYPE_MONO;
options.inputFormat = VrVideoView.Options.FORMAT_HLS;             
videoWidgetView.loadVideo(Uri.parse("https://youtu.be/DlcBadfFUC0"), options);
```

My Full MainActivity.java file is:

```
package com.example.kurtc.vr_test_2;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoEventListener;
import com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * Preserve the video's state when rotating the phone.
 */
private static final String STATE_IS_PAUSED = "isPaused";
private static final String STATE_PROGRESS_TIME = "progressTime";
/**
 * The video duration doesn't need to be preserved, but it is saved in this example. This allows
 * the seekBar to be configured during {@link #onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)} rather than waiting
 * for the video to be reloaded and analyzed. This avoid UI jank.
 */
private static final String STATE_VIDEO_DURATION = "videoDuration";


private VideoLoaderTask backgroundVideoLoaderTask;

/**
 * The video view and its custom UI elements.
 */
protected VrVideoView videoWidgetView;

/**
 * Seeking UI & progress indicator. The seekBar's progress value represents milliseconds in the
 * video.
 */
private SeekBar seekBar;

private ImageButton volumeToggle;
private ImageButton playToggle;
protected ImageView playIcon;
private boolean isMuted;

/**
 * By default, the video will start playing as soon as it is loaded. This can be changed by using
 * {@link VrVideoView#pauseVideo()} after loading the video.
 */
private boolean isPaused = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBarListener());

    videoWidgetView = (VrVideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
    videoWidgetView.setEventListener(new ActivityEventListener());

    volumeToggle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.volume_toggle);
    volumeToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setIsMuted(!isMuted);
        }
    });

    playToggle = (ImageButton) findViewById((R.id.play_toggle));
    playToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            handlePause();
        }
    });

    playIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    playIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    playIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            handlePause();
        }
    });


    // Load the bitmap in a background thread to avoid blocking the UI thread. This operation can
    // take 100s of milliseconds.
    if (backgroundVideoLoaderTask != null) {
        // Cancel any task from a previous intent sent to this activity.
        backgroundVideoLoaderTask.cancel(true);
    }
    backgroundVideoLoaderTask = new VideoLoaderTask();
    backgroundVideoLoaderTask.execute("https://youtu.be/DlcBadfFUC0");
}

//playbutton replaced: volume_off, volume_on
private void setIsMuted(boolean isMuted) {
    this.isMuted = isMuted;
    volumeToggle.setImageResource(isMuted ? R.drawable.playbutton : R.drawable.playbutton);
    videoWidgetView.setVolume(isMuted ? 0.0f : 1.0f);
}


private void handlePause() {
    togglePause();
    updatePauseButtons();
}

//playbutton replaced: play_off, play_on
private void updatePauseButtons(){
    playToggle.setImageResource(isPaused ? R.drawable.playbutton : R.drawable.playbutton);
    playIcon.setVisibility(isPaused ? View.VISIBLE: View.INVISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putLong(STATE_PROGRESS_TIME, videoWidgetView.getCurrentPosition());
    savedInstanceState.putLong(STATE_VIDEO_DURATION, videoWidgetView.getDuration());
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean(STATE_IS_PAUSED, isPaused);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    long progressTime = savedInstanceState.getLong(STATE_PROGRESS_TIME);
    videoWidgetView.seekTo(progressTime);
    seekBar.setMax((int) savedInstanceState.getLong(STATE_VIDEO_DURATION));
    seekBar.setProgress((int) progressTime);

    isPaused = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_IS_PAUSED);
    if (isPaused) {
        videoWidgetView.pauseVideo();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Prevent the view from rendering continuously when in the background.
    videoWidgetView.pauseRendering();
    // If the video is playing when onPause() is called, the default behavior will be to pause
    // the video and keep it paused when onResume() is called.
    isPaused = true;
    updatePauseButtons();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Resume the 3D rendering.
    videoWidgetView.resumeRendering();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // Destroy the widget and free memory.
    videoWidgetView.shutdown();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void togglePause() {
    if (isPaused) {
        videoWidgetView.playVideo();
    } else {
        videoWidgetView.pauseVideo();
    }
    isPaused = !isPaused;
}

/**
 * When the user manipulates the seek bar, update the video position.
 */
private class SeekBarListener implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser) {
            videoWidgetView.seekTo(progress);
        } // else this was from the ActivityEventHandler.onNewFrame()'s seekBar.setProgress update.
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
}

/**
 * Listen to the important events from widget.
 */
private class ActivityEventListener extends VrVideoEventListener {
    /**
     * Called by video widget on the UI thread when it's done loading the video.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLoadSuccess() {
        seekBar.setMax((int) videoWidgetView.getDuration());
    }

    /**
     * Called by video widget on the UI thread on any asynchronous error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLoadError(String errorMessage) {
        // An error here is normally due to being unable to decode the video format.
        Toast.makeText(
                MainActivity.this, "Error loading video: " + errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick() {

    }

    /**
     * Update the UI every frame.
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewFrame() {
        seekBar.setProgress((int) videoWidgetView.getCurrentPosition());
    }

    /**
     * Make the video play in a loop. This method could also be used to move to the next video in
     * a playlist.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCompletion() {
        videoWidgetView.seekTo(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Helper class to manage threading.
 */
class VideoLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... fileInformation) {
        try {
            VrVideoView.Options options = new VrVideoView.Options();

            options.inputType = VrVideoView.Options.TYPE_MONO;
            options.inputFormat = VrVideoView.Options.FORMAT_HLS;
            videoWidgetView.loadVideo(Uri.parse("https://youtu.be/DlcBadfFUC0"), options);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // An error here is normally due to being unable to locate the file.
            // Since this is a background thread, we need to switch to the main thread to show a toast.
            videoWidgetView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast
                            .makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error opening file. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        }

        return true;
    }
}
}
```

My activity_main.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
            <com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoView
                android:id="@+id/video_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:layout_height="250dip"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id = "@+id/playButton"
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                android:background="@drawable/playbutton"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/play_toggle"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/playbutton" />
        <!-- Seeking UI & progress indicator. play_on  volume_on -->
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:layout_width="0dp"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/volume_toggle"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingStart="0dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/playbutton"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kurtc.vr_test_2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. As is, your question has too much code. Trim down the code to a [mcve] please. What happens when you run your code? Wat do you expect to happen instead? Include any error messages and tack traces you may get.

Comment: The error I get when I try to load the link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DlcBadfFUC0&t=7s) is:
Error loading video:
    com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.deps.gx: None of the available extractors (cq,db, dd, cu, dy, dw, er, cj, dm, em, et, ch) could read the stream.

Comment: I have found that the following link (https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8) works with VrVideoView.options.FORMAT_HLS, and the link (http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4) works with VrVideoView.options.FORMAT_DEFAULT. So, I guess my problem that I am trying to figure out is how I can get a link like either of the two I just mentioned from google drive?